# Pulling value of the function in to a Variable

Tags: powershell

The function Get-loggedOnUser shows 3 items, and the code can be found here  [LoggedInUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925771/active-logged-in-users-on-remote-machine)

1. Computer Name
2. Logged on user
3. Sid of the user

I would like to be able to take the results of the LoggedOnUser function (only need the logged in user) and pipe the results to the variable below called Username.

```
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    function Get-LoggedOnUser

    $credential = Get-Credential
    $computers = "MachineName"

    foreach ($machine in $computers)
    {
    Get-LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $machine
    $username = $_.LoggedOn
    $sid = ((get-aduser $username).SID).Value

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machine -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock { New-PSDrive -Name HKU -PSProvider Registry -Root Registry::HKEY_USERS; New-ItemProperty -Path "HKU:\$($args[0])\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -PropertyType String -Name AutoConfigURL -Value "http://proxy.domain.com/proxies/proxy.pac" -Force } -argumentlist $sid
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$loggedOn=Get-LoggedOnUser -computername $machine
$username = $loggedOn.LoggedOn
$sid = $loggedOn.Sid #as this is already returned from above funtion
$sid = ((get-aduser $username).sid).value #if you want to still get it from AD
```