# How to schedule Azure VM turn on/off with powershellscript if no active users?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I've seen some questions regarding turning on and off azure vm with powershell scripts for instance this powershell script to turn off Azure VM 
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Stop-Azure-Classic-VMs-7a4ae43e#content. 
But I can't find out if it's possible to turn off Azure VM at x time but only the ones with no active users. And if any active users try again next hour or something like that.

Is it possible to turn on/off Azure VM with a schedueled powershell script and only turn off machines with no active users? in that case, how?

Comment: what you could do is : 
write a powershell function which looks for active sessions, and use that to check : here's an example of how this should look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925771/active-logged-in-users-on-remote-machine

Comment: Not sure how PowerShell is going to help you - you'll first have to come up with some way of calculating `number of active users` - there's no such metric on an Azure VM, since there's no way to know what it means for your app to have an active user. This is something you'd need to implement, and how you do this is totally up to you - not something that can be answered on StackOverflow.